# Angular: Parser Error: Private identifiers are not supported. Unexpected private identifier

Tags: angular13

I am prototyping a functionality I am just doing things simple here. I know the benefits of FormArray but I want to be simple here.

I am getting this:

Parser Error: Private identifiers are not supported. Unexpected private identifier

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let marca of marcas">

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <span> {{ marca.nome }} </span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
       
        <input #searchBar placeholder="categoria ML" class="form form-control" > 
       
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">

    <button (click)="salvarCategoria(marca, #searchBar.value)" class="btn btn-primary" >salvar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's the #searchBar that is causing it. I think it's a valid syntax isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using #searchBar to reference the template variable of the `<input>` element. The **#** (hash) is unescessary here. You should just use **searchbar** instead of **#searchbar**. see: https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables

corrected code:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let marca of marcas">

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <span> {{ marca.nome }} </span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
       
        <input #searchBar placeholder="categoria ML" class="form form-control" > 
       
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">

    #This line changed (seachBar.value instead of #searchBar.value)
    <button (click)="salvarCategoria(marca, searchBar.value)" class="btn btn-primary" >salvar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the third line from the bottom, use

```
    <button (click)="salvarCategoria(marca, searchBar.value)" ...
```

instead of

```
    <button (click)="salvarCategoria(marca, #searchBar.value)" ...
                                     <!--   ^ error here. -->
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Angular is changing thing, luck it has lots of features to work as a workaround.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let marca of marcas">

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <span> {{ marca.nome }} </span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">
       
        <input [(ngModel)]="marca.idCategoriaMercadoLivre" placeholder="categoria ML" class="form form-control" > 
       
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">

    <button (click)="salvarCategoria(marca)" class="btn btn-primary" >salvar</button>
    </div>


</div>
```

I used this

[(ngModel)]="marca.idCategoriaMercadoLivre"

and this

(click)="salvarCategoria(marca)"